# Dial Up Connection Using Sim900

Tags: sim900

I want to connect my raspberry pi system to internet via sim900 gsm modem by at commands for that i have used the following at commands

```
AT
ATH
ATE1
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","www"
ATD*99#
```

It shows connect but i am unable to browse the internet please help me how to configure serial port for default internet connection in raspberry pi and give me the guidance for at commands to connect internet

Comment: did you enter those commands from a program like minicom?

Comment: You'll need to use something like `pppd` to issue those commands and then setup a TCP/IP stack over the serial port. At that point your system will get an IP address and then you should be able to use the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the reply How to Issue PPPD command

Answer (score 1):

Do you use the command

```
AT+IFC=2,2
```

and

```
AT+CIPMODE=1
```

it works fine!

You are trying to use a dial-up connection, it means you have a stack tcp/ip side of raspberry pi! no the module!